# Determining necessary array length to store input

Tags: c, arrays

What's the best way to determine the length of an input stream in `Stdin` so that you can create an array of the correct length to store it using, say, `getchar()`?

Is there some way of peeking at all the characters in the input stream and using something like:

```
while((ch = readchar()) != "\n" ) {
    count++;
}
```

and then creating the array with size count?

Comment: can you pass at command line?

Comment: The usual approach is to grow the array dynamically as you read and fill it in. This is (a) probably faster than reading the input twice and (b) the only way if the input stream is not seekable. (Code that works for all streams is more reusable than code that only works for seekable streams.)

Comment: @Grijesh Well yes, but suppose I don't want to rely on the user to accurately count the number of characters in a paragraph or something.

Comment: The case that clearly breaks this approach: `stdin` is the console and the user's typing something longer than the keyboard buffer ;)

Comment: If standard input is a disk file (`program < file`), then you can use `fseek()` and `ftell()`, or on POSIX you can use `stat()`.  If the input could be a pipe, terminal, socket, FIFO, etc, then you can't seek on the standard input and you have to allocate as you go. Do not allocate a single extra character at a time; it becomes prohibitively expensive.  Use a size doubling rule, as in [Marian](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3125194/marian)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21354188).

Comment: Can anyone be bothered to find a good previous question of which this is a duplicate? Frankly, I suspect it is harder work than leaving this alone, but the equivalent has been asked and answered many times before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the time I typed the code, there are several similar answers. I am afraid you will need to do something like:

```
int  size = 1;
char *input = malloc(size);
int  count = 0;
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' ) {
    input[count++] = ch;
    if (count >= size) {
         size = size * 2;
         input = realloc(input, size);
    }
}
input[count++] = 0;
input = realloc(input, count);
```

Alternatively you can use the same as a POSIX library function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html). I.e.

```
int count, size;
char *input = NULL;
count = getline(&input, &size, stdin);
```

In both cases, do not forget to free input once you have finished with it.

Comment: +1. For a production implementation, of course, you need to check the return of all calls to `malloc` and `realloc` to make sure they are not NULL. Also this implementation permits NULL characters in the input, which makes it tricky to interpret the result reliably...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just starting C so I gotta learn all this pointer stuff properly. Quick question: why do you need to add an extra 0? Why can't you just `input = realloc(input, count)` straight after the loop?

Comment: Not really needed. However it has a twofold effect, you can use all the string related functions on `input` and it is sure that count != 0 in the last line.

Comment: Note that the code `input = realloc(input, size);` is a minor disaster if the memory reallocation ever fails.  Prior to the call, there was one pointer to the memory `input`. If the reallocation fails, `input` has been set to null, so there's no way to access the previously (and still) allocated memory any more — a memory leak.  For growing allocations (where the space allocated increases), always use a variant on `void *new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_space == 0) …handle out of memory…; old_ptr = new_ptr;`.  For shrinking reallocations like the last, you're OK. Always check!

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no way. You can peek only one character ahead, so if you use code like in your example, the characters are read already, and even if you know their count and can allocate the memory, you cannot read them again.
The possible strategy is to allocate some memory at the beginning, and then in the loop if you are hitting the limit reallocate the memory, doubling the length.

Answer (score 0):

The one way to do this with typical unix files is to use the `fseek` system call to determine the size of the file. Unfortunately, `STDIN` is often not a seekable stream.

The only way to handle the general case I know of is to simply use dynamic memory allocation. You make the best guess with an initial buffer and them once you reach the end, you `malloc` a new array and start all over again. Mistakes in handling this process are the start of many classic security bugs.